# Paypal's Redirect URL asks to log in when already logged in

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox

When checking out, we use a chained payment which we send over via the classic Java SDK. It then sends back a payKey which we use when constructing the redirect url. This has been working fine for 6 months in our sandbox environment which points to a url similar to "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-02Y91986YY463074B". Now, when my browser hits that generated link it asks me to log in but I'm already logged in. I'm logged in to developer.paypal.com as well as x.com.

Side Note: When I logged in, I saw my test accounts were not listed any more so I ran the importer tool that was listed on the page.

I suppose my question is: Has anyone else experienced the 'Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features.' page even after they have logged in? If so, what steps did you take to have it recognize you were logged in.

Comment: This is a complaint, not a question.

Comment: I suppose so...the problem is that the first link paypal provides on this page (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support) is stackoverflow. That being said the stackoverflow community responds a lot faster than the paypal community so there is the outside hope that someone has had my experience and knows resolution.

Comment: Formulate it as a question, and as precise of one as you can (i.e. not just "how do I fix this").  [It will help you solve this.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I am unsure of the exact cause, the solution was to clear my entire browsing history including cookies. Once I logged back in, everything worked.